# Cannot invoke initializer for type NSAttributedString with an argument list of type (string: String, attributes: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm migrating code from XCode 6.4 to 7 and this error doesn't seem resolvable.

```
func onHoldReasonAttributedTextSetup(onHoldReson : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{

    let markerFontAttributes : [NSObject : AnyObject]? = [
      NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 152/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
    ]
    let onHoldText = NSAttributedString(string: "On Hold: ", attributes: markerFontAttributes)
    let onHoldReasonText  = NSAttributedString(string:onHoldReson)
    var string = NSMutableAttributedString()
    string.appendAttributedString(onHoldText)
    string.appendAttributedString(onHoldReasonText)
    return string
}
```

Comment: use like `let markerFontAttributes = [
      NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 152/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
    ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
let markerFontAttributes : [NSObject : AnyObject]? = [
      NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 152/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
    ]
```

to

```
let markerFontAttributes : [String : AnyObject]? = [
      NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 152/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
    ]
```

Because the initialiser expects attributed dictionary in `[String : AnyObject]?` format:

```
init(string str: String, attributes attrs: [String : AnyObject]?)
```

Reference : [NSAttributedString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithString:attributes:)

Comment: You cal also drop the type declaration altogether, Swift 2 should infer the type properly.

Comment: @EricD. Yes, you are correct. In this case, no need of specifying the type